# How to redirect my web in EC2 to my domain

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, domainservices

I have a web site on EC2 running with tomcat(8080), and in the same instance I have apache2 (80) to give statical files (image) to a android app. I need both, but it's not neccesary that it collaborate.

Well, my question is if I have this url : http://ec2-54-72-116-252.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/OcioTurismoMontoro
How can I redirect my www.montoroturismo.tk to it?
In the domain panel I only can put the ip of my hosting but neither the port either the context (/OcioTurismoMontoro) .

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manage port forwarding on the instance itself. If you want to serve something else on port 80, may be you can create virtual host on Apache. Put this in `<Apache>/conf/sites-enabled/OcioTurismoMontoro.conf:`

```
<virtualhost *:80>

      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName www.montoroturismo.tk
      ProxyRequests off
      <proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      </proxy>
      ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/OcioTurismoMontoro/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/OcioTurismoMontoro/
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need mod proxy for Apache.